# Updated power play rules for an ODI?

Tags: rules, cricket

I've read the updated "power play" rules which were modified in June 2016 on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerplay_(cricket)). But then have a slight confusion on when can the fielding team request for the power play.

> - Mandatory powerplay (1–10 overs):In an uninterrupted match (i.e. 50
>     overs), the first 10 overs of an innings will be a mandatory
>     powerplay. During the mandatory powerplay only two fielders are
>     allowed outside the 30-yard circle.
> - Between overs 11 and 40 a maximum of four fielders are allowed outside the 30-yard circle
> - In the final 10 overs (41–50) a maximum of five fielders will be allowed to field outside the 30-yard circle

So "P1" is the mandatory power play ("Bowling Powerplay") and what's P2? If so between which overs they can take it and how many overs is the second power play?

Is that last ten overs considered as a power play too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (Standard ODI) Playing Conditions quoted and cited are from July 2015. They were not updated recently to the time of asking.

When playing under such conditions, there is no request for a power play by either team. The three power plays, the limits of which you have stated, are all mandatory.

The ICC World Cup 2015 featured variance from the Standard. Clause 41.2.5 therein allowed for two power plays:

- the mandatory P1 (overs 1 to 10)
- the batting P2 (5 overs, completed no later than overs 36 to 40)

As such, there was no fielding power play, and one could not be requested at any time.

Comment: So the `batting powerplay` still exists? Thought it was removed??

Comment: No. Please read the answer again: under standard conditions, all power plays are mandatory, they are not associated with any team. The 2015 CWC had the option, this was a sole exception.

Comment: Thanks. To be make myself clear, the batting PP was opted out only during the WC and it does exist as a normal ODI power play as of now.

Comment: No - the exact opposite. The 2015 Conditions eliminated all types of optional power play. The CWC had an exception which *included* the batting power play change.

Comment: Since 2015 WC was an exception, that doesn't mean it'll be continued in all the upcoming WCs as well na?

Comment: Each CWC seems to receive its own playing conditions, so the use or absence of team power plays won't be known until they're released.